# Run bash or python script at startup raspbian

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, operating-system, raspbian

i want to asking about :

i have a python script send data to Mysql, so i need to run this script on the startup of my OS. the script path : /home/pi/Desktop/data.py

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your command to your .bashrc, and it will run as your OS startup.

```
echo "python /path/script" >> ~/.bashrc
```